# delphi mysql ado connectivity

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe3

I'm trying to get an ADO connection working in Delphi XE3 and am having major difficulty.

I have an ODBC driver installed on my machine (Win7 x64) the driver shows as 'mySQL ODBC 5.1 driver' under ODBC data sources.  Mysql version 5.5.

My understanding is that I should be able to put a TadoConnection component on the form and then assign an appropriate connection string to it as below:

```
var
  conn: TADOConnection;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  conn := conn.Create(nil);
  conn.ConnectionString := 'DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=myserver; PORT=3306; DATABASE=mysql; UID=myuser; PASSWORD=mypassword;OPTION=3;';
  conn.Connected := true;
end;
```

When I run the application and click the button, I get an error

> Project Project1.exe raised exception class EOleException with message '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified'.

Can anyone help me? What have I missed?  I've tried looking for examples on the web and have had no joy so far..  Any advice is greatly received...

Comment: Most likely you have configured with C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe
instedad of C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

Comment: This is usually a problem of installing the 64-bit driver and then trying to access it from 32-bit code (or vice versa). Are both the driver and your executable the same "bitness" (eg., both 32-bit or both 64-bit)? If so, did you configure the 32-bit ODBC driver (as mentioned by @bummi above)? (The default in Control Panel is the 64-bit ODBC administrator.)

Comment: I think that you could both be onto something.  I have opened syswow64\odbcad32.exe and there is no driver available in there.  Does that mean that I have got the wrong driver?  Which one should I have?  I have a 32 bit code base, so should I use a 32 bit driver - I presume that the driver I have is 32 bit as if I open system32\odbcad32.exe the driver shows if I click add (and not in the syswow64\odbcad32.exe)...  Thank you

Comment: For reference - turns out that the comments left were spot on.  I had to remove the existing driver and install the 32 bit version of mysql odbc connector (x86, 32-bit).  Used latest version so the connection string driver reads 'DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2a Driver}'.

Comment: why u use ADO ? that looks a bit tricky chain: Delphi -> ADO -> ODBC ->mySQL.
Perhaps u can get native OLEDB driver to MySQL ? Or perhaps u can use native for Delphi tools like DB Express, ZeosDB, AnyDAC, UniDAC ?

Especially given that Microsoft is deprecating ADO starting new project with ADO seems objectable direction. Or at least maybe u can surf through Torry and get some direct ODBC connection component for Delphi.

Comment: thanks for the idea  @Arioch'the.  I've moved to DB Express as per your suggestion.  ODBC wasn't an option after a little working (it too had its own challenges), I now have a working connection which appears to be quick and reliable.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped. But since u're making choice for next few years, i'd suggest you to evaluate all the options. DBX is easy to stick with, because i is branded by Embarcadero. But novadays i am not sure that is benefit...

Answer (score 1):

You just have to check your ODBC Drivers... Go to control panel.. Administrative Tools... and check which ODBC Driver version u have... Then use the right one... For example, I am using the last version of MySQL ODBC. Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver}